# Retrying with Spring Retry based on error message or status code?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-retry

I am using the spring-retry dependency and currently have a Java Spring Boot application class annotated with @EnableRetry, and a function annotated with the below

```
@Retryable(value = MongoException.class,
   maxAttempts = 4, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 100))
```

This allows me to retry for all exceptions of type MongoException for the function. However, id like to retry based on a specific status code or even an error message that is thrown. Is this possible to achieve with Spring Retry?

Comment: You may want to use this https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/annotation/Retryable.html#exceptionExpression--

Answer (score 0):

In the `@Retryable` method, catch the exception; then:

```
RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().setExhaustedOnly()`
```

and rethrow it (or another exception type).

will disable retries and go straight to the `@Recover` method, if supplied, otherwise it will be thrown to the caller.

Or, as indicated in @geobreze comment above, use an `exceptionExpression` https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/annotation/Retryable.html#exceptionExpression--